# height=100% not rendering the google maps api

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, height

I am trying to use the Google Maps API.  I have gotten a authorization key and pasted in the sample code they gave us, but I can't make the map render even when they tell me to make sure I put a height of 100% on both my map div and the body.

I have tried and it won't show up. If I put a 500px height on the map div, and give the body a 100% height it works... but I want to know why height of 100% will not will not render. I am copying exactly what the Google documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple) is giving me and what the video tells me to double check. HELP, i am insanely curious on why 100% height won't render. I want to use percentages, so that it can be compatible on mobile devices!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ice Cream</title>

        <!-- Google Docs-->


    <!-- external CSS link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>


    </head>


<body>


<div id='map_canvas'> HELLOooo <!--dimensions of map are set in CSS-->
</div>


    <!-- external CSS link -->
    <!-- javascript -->
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDuDCh7Odrr4RUUiAHMyDtfwC2NtySy-64"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>



</body>
</html>


body, #map_canvas{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;



}


  $(function() {
    console.log("hi");

   function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

console.log('map');



  });
```

Comment: Try adding a min-height:100% as well.  I'm guessing the body isn't as tall as you think it is.  Add in a html { height:100%} too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why 100% doesn't work is because the map needs to send you images at a specific ratio (fixed `width` & `height`). Now I might be guessing here, but that's what I think happens.

Since I had a similar problem, where my map was hidden inside a tab, I wrote this function to calculate the width & height or a ratio. Then whatever size of the container, the map was in, it would adjust. It uses jQuery so I just thought I'd post it to get the idea.

```
    /**
     * Calculate the dimensions
     */
    calculateMap: function () {
        var self = this,
            parent = this.map.parent(), // jQuery obj
            w, h, id, el;

        // if the container of your map is visible and wrapped it has a certain width and height...
        // if it also has 100% height, it could be collapsed (not wrapped)
        // so you ask the google maps api to load images at 500px width and 0height?
        // if the parent has 0height, the ratio helps to set it properly
        // with debug tools (F12) you can see the parent if it lights up
        if (parent.is(':visible')) {
            w = parent.outerWidth(false);
            h = w * this.settings.options.mapRatio; // 4/3 | 16/9
            this.map.css({ width: w, height: h });
        } else {
            // if your map is invisible after load...
            id = this.onParent.prop('id'); // this id references my tab
            el = this.onParent.prevAll().find('a[href=#' + id + ']'); // trigger of the tab
            // add click event once
            el.one(this.settings.events.onParent, function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    self.activate(); // goes back to calculateMap()
                }, 200);
            }.bind(this));
        }
    },
```

If you trigger `calculateMap` on the `resize` event, you'll have a responsive approach.

Also a quick google showed me [this approach](http://www.labnol.org/internet/embed-responsive-google-maps/28333/) ... notice the fixed width and height on the iframe.

In short:

- fixed width and height in css gives you the cleanest solution.  you might be able to use a clearfix, `padding` in `%` or `min-height` in `px` to gain dimension if that works out.
- For dynamic/event loading I suggest JavaScript or jQuery
- or with an iframe and a fixed width and height

Answer (score 1):

The browser needs to be able to calculate a non-zero height.  You need to set the height of the `html` element to 100% also:

```js
  $(function() {
    console.log("hi");

   function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

console.log('map');



  });
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id='map_canvas'> HELLOooo <!--dimensions of map are set in CSS-->
</div>
```