# Unable to cover complete body element by google map

Tags: html, css

I am working on some web app where I wanted to cover complete html/body element with google map but unable to find out the proper solution...

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body,html{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;}

#map {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;}
```

I have included normalize.css file in my code. Please, tell me what I am doing wrong..? **Its working with absolute positioning, not with other position properties**.

Comment: A duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/28522955/1402138 perhaps?

Comment: Also you will need to remove your built in default `margin` and/or `padding` valuess from your elements.

Comment: @Saurabh I've tried your css, its working, have a look https://fiddle.jshell.net/4j2ot8g0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working fine by specifying height in **'viewport height'** format.

```
#map{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you just use min-height on the map id?

```
body,html{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0;
    }

#map {
    min-height: 100%;
    border: solid 1px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you don't need to use positioning simply use

```
#map{
    height: 100vh;
    width:100%;
}
```