# Google Maps API: Problems with Map height

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Following the recent changes Google have made to their API, I've had to rework all the pages I have involving maps. After many hours of work it is all back working, with just a couple of niggling issues. Here's the first one:

On some pages I open the map in a floatbox (www.floatboxjs.com) with the line

```
<a href="../maps/map_hotel.php?<?php echo "hid=".$hid ?>" class="floatbox locmap" data-fb-options="caption:`<?php echo $row_hotel['hotel'];?>` scrolling:no">See location map</a>
```

Then map_hotel.php consists of a single div within the body. If I specify the height of that div as a percentage, the map doesn't display.

```
html {height:100%}
body{height:100%;margin:0;padding:0}
#mapCanvas {height:100%;}
table.infowin, table.infowin tr, table.infowin td{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;background-color:#FFF;color:#666}
table.infowin td.pic{vertical-align:top}
td.pic img{margin-bottom:4px;border:none}
a{text-decoration:none}
.hotel{font-size:1.2em;font-weight:bold;color:#3498db}
.gm-style-iw{padding:6px;width:230px !important;border:1px solid #666;background-color:#fff}
```

If I specify the height in pixels, it does. Why should that be? Given the wide variety of devices that will be used to view it, a fixed height is pretty unsatisfactory.

Comment: The parent element doesn't have a height, so the browser doesn't know what the percentage is of.

Comment: related question: [height=100% not rendering the google maps api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522687/height-100-not-rendering-the-google-maps-api)

Comment: I've edited my question to show the CSS I'm using. html and body are already set at 100% too. I've also tried the min-height suggestion on that related question and that does nothing. I've also tried height:inherit and height:auto.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  Does `map_hotel.php` have a `<html>` and/or `<body>` tag(s)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: I updated Floatbox from version 7.5.1 to 8.1.1 and the problem went away. I couldn't find anything in the Floatbox change log to suggest that it would overcome this problem (which had only just appeared with the changes I had been forced to make) but it did.